# Install python function from git URL

Tags: git, pip, installation

I am trying to install the following function in python via the command line:

https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi/blob/master/ipython/bsm_functions.py

Within the cmd, I tried a combination of functions including the following:

```
pip install bsm_functions    
pip install https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi/blob/master/ipython/bsm_functions.py
pip install git+https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi/blob/master/ipython/bsm_functions.py
```

The specific errors I am getting is:
"Error [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing comm and git clone -q https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi/blob/master/ipython/bsm_functions.py"

Am not sure how to make this work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Error/warning output? Explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the error  "Error [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing comm and git clone -q https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi/blob/master/ipython/bsm_functions.py"

Comment: I'm assuming this is windows since you mentioned cmd, are you sure you have the correct file paths installed for pip, as well as for git? These type of errors are common on windows environments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clone a file from a repository. Either install the entire package via pip or download one file and install it manually.

Comment: I am having a slow code day... I guessed at the url a few times, for example "pip install git+https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi.git" but it says it cannot find the right file. How do I find the right url based on the git address?

Comment: See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support. The command must be something like `pip install git+https://github.com/yhilpisch/py4fi.git#egg=py4fit`.